# Is it possible to add different items into android listview

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

i have a ListView in my application, i fetch contacts from user phonebook then displays them into ListView, now what i want to do is to add different child views into ListView item based on some condition like my application check each phonebook contact for it's availability on server database and what i want to achieve is to add voice/video call buttons for that particular contact and add invite button for all other contacts that are not available in database.

My condition applies on these three child's of ListView item, voice call button, video call button and invite button and my condition is if user is available in database then i only want to display voice/video call button and hide invite button but if the user is not available then i wan to display invite button and hide audio/video call buttons

ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_listview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contact_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feel The Light" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home" />



</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_audio_call_dark"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_video_call_dark"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Invite"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_green_oval"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ContactsFragment

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {
private static final String LOG_TAG = ContactsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public ContactsAdapter(Activity context, List<ContactItem> contactItems) {
    super(context, 0, contactItems);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ContactItem contactItem = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_icon);
    contactImage.setImageResource(contactItem.contactImage);

    TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
    contactName.setText(contactItem.contactName);

    TextView contactNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_number);
    contactNumber.setText(contactItem.contactNumber);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

ContactsFragment

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends Fragment {

private ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter;

public static ContactsListFragment newInstance() {
    return new ContactsListFragment();
}

public ContactsListFragment() {

}

ArrayList<String> contactName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> contactNumber = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<ContactItem> contactsAvailable = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ContactItem> contactsInvite = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null
    );

    String currentNumber = "";

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        number = number.replaceAll(" ", "");

        char c = number.charAt(0);
        char c1 = number.charAt(1);
        String s = Character.toString(c)+Character.toString(c1);

        if (s.equals("00")) {
            number = number.replaceAll("00", "+");
        }

        if (number.length() == 12) {
            number = "+" + number;
        }

        if (number.length() == 13) {
            if (!currentNumber.equals(number)) {
                contactName.add(name);
                contactNumber.add(number);
            }

        }

        currentNumber = number;

    }

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_list, container, false);

    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(50);

    QBUsers.getUsersByLogins(contactNumber, pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers, Bundle bundle) {
            for (int i = 0; i < qbUsers.size(); i++) {
                ContactItem contactItem = new ContactItem(qbUsers.get(i).getFullName(), qbUsers.get(i).getLogin(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                contactsAvailable.add(contactItem);

            }

            contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(), contactsAvailable);

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_listview_available);
            listView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



    return rootView;

}
}
```

Comment: Please add a question into your text. You've described what you want to do and added code but have not explained what's not working

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

1. Add a `boolean` flag `isAvailableInDB` in your `ContactItem.java` class.
2. Get contact list from your `phonebook` and check one by one with your server `database`.
3. If a `contactItem` exist in your `database` just set flag `isAvailableInDB` as `true` oterwise `false` for that `contactItem`.
4. After that add `contactItem` to `ArrayList`
5. Create `ContactsAdapter` and set it to `ListView`
6. Finally, add a condition in your adapter's `getView()` method to check the `contactItem` flag `isAvailableInDB`. If `true`, show voice/video call button & hide invite button and if `false`, show invite button & hide voice/video call button.

**Give an id to XML button's:**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_voice_call"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_audio_call_dark"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_video_call"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_video_call_dark"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_invite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Invite"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_green_oval"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

**In your adapter's getView() method:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ContactItem contactItem = getItem(position);

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, parent, false);
}

ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_icon);
contactImage.setImageResource(contactItem.contactImage);

TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
contactName.setText(contactItem.contactName);

TextView contactNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_number);
contactNumber.setText(contactItem.contactNumber);

ImageButton buttonVoiceCall= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_voice_call);
ImageButton buttonVideoCall= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_video_call);
Button buttonVoiceCall= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_invite);

if(contactItem.getIsAvailableInDB())
{
     buttonVoiceCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     buttonVideoCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     buttonInvite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
     buttonVoiceCall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     buttonVideoCall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     buttonInvite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
return convertView;
}
```

Hope this will help you~

Comment: @user7661245 if my answer seems useful please give an up vote. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flag on the ContactItem class and set it true or false, if it is available in the Database and then set the visibility of the buttons in the adapter according to this flag.